# Does envoyproxy have a status page similar to the HAProxy status page?

Tags: envoyproxy

HAProxy has a status page (https://tecadmin.net/how-to-configure-haproxy-statics/) that lists the backends and frontends (essentially info in a GUI about the endpoints and their health checks.)

Is there a similar GUI in envoyProxy ?

Answer (score 0):

Envoy does not have a GUI but does expose lots and lots of metrics, checkout /stats on the admin port for example.

See https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/operations/admin.html for the docs.